# is there any method that how much time a user spent on every post he visit on my social media app

Tags: android, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I want the time spent by the users on a particular post on my social media app, so I can get the data and implement it in the ML model so I can show similar post like that

Comment: There's no in built method for that, you can build that on your own & it is not that hard.
Implement your logic (save current time in millis) in the relevant activity's onCreate, then in onDestroy/onPause/onStart or whatever suits best, get current time, get the difference between both the time & save it along with the Post data. You should use Firebase Analytics for this.

Comment: can you tell me what exactly this thing is called please